# How to access LocalDB in asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, localdb

I want to access localDB.
My connection string in sql server is like below

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Tv3-20171226095229.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Tv3-20171226095229;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And my mdf file is in app_data like this

[image]

i am using following code to access the database like below:

```
public static DataSet GetDataSetFromStoredProc(string sql, Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary, string _ConnectionString)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection2);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> pair in dictionary)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                    }
                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error. " + err.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

public static DataTable GetDataTableFromStoredProc(string sql, Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary, string _ConnectionString)
            {
                DataSet ds = GetDataSetFromStoredProc(sql, dictionary,_ConnectionString);

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    return ds.Tables[0];
                return null;
            }
```

Now i am executing the function like below:

```
GetDataTableFromStoredProc("down_data", dictionary, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)
```

but i am geting an exception like below:

> Data error. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
>   Application event log for error details. )

How to solve this??

Comment: is the .mdf file added to the project?

Comment: @RomanSvitukha Yes

Comment: _When/Where_ are you running this? In VS/Debug or some "production" environment. See [SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb), particularly _permissions_ and _user instance_ topics.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "Initial Catalog=aspnet-Tv3-20171226095229; " from the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user Integrated Security=SSPI